# Spring @Sql annotation insert MySQL timestamp in UTC

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have next sql to be executed before my `@DataJpaTest`

```
insert into run_history(id, start_timestamp)
values (1, '2018-06-26 03:30:00');
```

But when I'm doing 
`repository.findAll()` I'm getting it as `2018-06-26T00:30:00Z` which means it has been saved in my local timezone.

Is there a way how to work in tests using UTC?